# Java get content from url

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to get a text from url using java.
I founded this answer on google:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    
System.out.println(s);
```

but how can I get the title of the page? the text? how to choose what to get from the url?

Comment: You'll probably need a library like JSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some of the `javax.swing.text.html` utility classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
//...
try{
    HTMLEditorKit htmlEditKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument) htmlEditKit.createDefaultDocument();
    HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
    parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new URL("https://www.google.com").openStream()),
            htmlDocument.getReader(0), true);
    System.out.println(htmlDocument.getProperty("title"));
} catch(IOException e){
    //Handle
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```